# SQL query with DESC do not working properly

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, join

I don't understund why sorting didin't work correctly with "ORDER BY average, votes DESC", because i need highest average and votes are going from the top to bottom, but DESC didin't solve what thing. My result in var_dump http://pastie.org/private/b05smuh0fvw72wwp2w1zq highest entrie is in the bottom, but i need start from the top and going to the bottom.

```
SELECT c.*, r.votes, c.total_comments,
       ROUND(sumrate / votes) AS average
FROM catalog c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.object_id, COUNT(*) as votes, SUM(r.rate) as sumrate
      FROM ratings r
      GROUP BY r.object_id
     ) r
     ON r.object_id = c.catalog_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.catalog_id, COUNT(*) as total_comments
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.catalog_id
     ) c
     ON c.catalog_id = c.catalog_id
GROUP BY c.catalog_id
ORDER BY average, votes DESC;
```

Comment: Just a note, that GROUP BY is invalid and not allowed in more recent MySQL versions. (If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.)

Comment: What do you mean? is that short table aliases in grouping? can you show example?

Answer (score 5):

Because you can define the order for every column and not just the `order by` in total. The default is `ASC`.

Your order

```
ORDER BY average, votes DESC
```

turn automatically into

```
ORDER BY average ASC, votes DESC
```

But you are looking for

```
ORDER BY average DESC, votes DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify DESC for both the columns. Otherwise by default it is ASC

```
SELECT c.*, r.votes, c.total_comments,
       ROUND(sumrate / votes) AS average
FROM catalog c LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT r.object_id, COUNT(*) as votes, SUM(r.rate) as sumrate
      FROM ratings r
      GROUP BY r.object_id
     ) r
     ON r.object_id = c.catalog_id LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT c.catalog_id, COUNT(*) as total_comments
      FROM comments c
      GROUP BY c.catalog_id
     ) c
     ON c.catalog_id = c.catalog_id
GROUP BY c.catalog_id
ORDER BY average DESC, votes DESC;
```